# Unregister commenting entirely from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to remove everything to do with comments from the wordpress admin in my theme (I'm guessing there is some way to do this through the functions.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Disable Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-comments/) plugin.